# Render/Update Thread synchronization

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm writing a small game with Libgdx.

I have aRender[OpenGL] thread that keeps calling `render()` on all objects and an
Update thread that keeps calling `update(double delta)` on all objects.

Update thread is looping way faster. Should I try to use some kind of synchronization so Update thread could rest for a bit ?
Would there be any benefits from it ?

**Update**

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        nano = System.nanoTime();
        long delta = nano - timestamp;
        timestamp = nano;
        accumulator+=(double)delta/BILION;
        while(accumulator >= step){
            update(step);
            accumulator-=step;
        }
        long loc = (long) ((step -accumulator)*1000)+1;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(loc);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I dont know if its a problem, but my current update is 2500-20000 fps. So Update speed is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data Update and your Render should be independent and not `synchronized`.

Your Update function should work at a speed that you determine will be the most user-friendly for the user.

It should be independent from Render since the rendering rate may change due to the hardware used by the end-user. 
And for example you don't want your "monster" to walk ten times faster on the last generation tablet so it would become unplayable.

You should set your update rate to a constant you choose.
Then maybe you'll want your update rate to slow down a bit if the framerate is really slow.

That's my opinion hoper it'll help.

Comment: What do you mean by "most user-friendly update speed"? My update runs as fast as it can get above minimal step. Update woks with given delta, so monster speed would be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a separate thread for update logic, there's just no reason to.

Why have your update method execute 5000 times a second, but rendering is capped at 60? That's a massive waste of resources.

The first line of your render method should called your update method.

Use `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` to get the time difference. You can trade off jerkyness on old/sluggish phones for smoother but slower updates by `Math.max(1 / 30f, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`. This will force a minimum update time of 30fps.